# When we need to go for size in terms of ps insted of px?

Tags: android

i am new to android..can any one tell when  we need to go for size in terms of ps insted of px?..thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

measurement types:

> px
> Pixels - corresponds to actual pixels on the screen.
>
> in
> Inches - based on the physical size of the screen.
>
> mm
> Millimeters - based on the physical size of the screen.
>
> pt
> Points - 1/72 of an inch based on the physical size of the screen.
>
> dp
> Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen. The ratio of dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, but not necessarily in direct proportion. Note: The compiler accepts both "dip" and "dp", though "dp" is more consistent with "sp".
>
> sp
> Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for both the screen density and user's preference.

source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

fill_parent attribute is used expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should use density-independent units (like dp) instead of pixels. There's a detailed guide with examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you mean 'pt' (or Points) instead of ps?

Px is short for pixels - use this if you want to be sure something is an absolute number of pixels in size. 'pt' is a publish measure meaning '1/72' of an inch. As this is a real-world measurement, it is not tied to pixels. Pixels can be of different sizes on different devices at different resolutions.

So, if you want to make sure something is of a certain real-world physical size, use 'pt' but if you want to make sure it is a set number of pixels, use px.